# Reading data from file using winapi

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I know that in winapi exist `ReadFile()` function for reading data from file, but I don't know how can I set the position of reading from file. Can I do this using WinAPI?

Comment: Use the [SetFilePointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: **Pro Tip**:  To find WinAPI functions related to a function you already know about, go to the MSDN page for the known function.  On the left will be a list of related functions to browse through.  You can find the MSDN page for almost any WinAPI function by typing "msdn" and the name of the function into your favorite search engine (for example, "msdn ReadFile").  You can also ascend to overview and usage pages for that block of WinAPI functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, unless you have a good reason for using the raw WinAPI, it's generally a better idea to use a cross-platform I/O library, such as C's stdio library or C++'s iostream library.  That way, your code is portable to any platform.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean seek to a particular location in a file with the Win32 API. Use the function 
`SetFilePointerEx`. But I still recommend `fseek()` and `fopen()`